# How to send alert at a certain time

Tags: time, alert, pine-script

I'd like to write a pine-script that will send me a report of the stock, says, it's pivot points, rsi, etc ... at 7am every morning and 3pm when mrkt close. I know how to do the alert, it's the trigger is I don't know how to tell it to send me the alert at 7am and 3pm.
Any thought on how to accomplish this? I look into timestamp or time, but don't know how to make that condition to send the alert.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of doing it, one of them is to create a session from time x to time y and get the start and the end of it.

I added comments for each section to see how it's working.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

//Sessions
session = input(title="Session", type=input.session, defval="0930-1555")

//Check if it's new bars
is_newbar2(sess) =>
    t = time("D", sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

//Check if it's in session
is_session(sess) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sess))
   
//Call the function
Session = is_session(session)

//Plot the background color to see the session
bgcolor(Session ? color.new(color.aqua, 95) : na)

//Start and end of the session
start = Session and not Session[1]
end = (not Session) and Session[1]

//Plot the start and the end of the session
plotshape(start, style=shape.labeldown, color = color.aqua, text = "Start", textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)
plotshape(end, style=shape.labeldown, color = color.purple, text = "End", textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)

//Alerts
if start
    alert("text alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if end
    alert("text alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

It's very important to write the starting of the session (if it start at 7am, then write exactly 07:00) and the time from the last candle of the session (if you are in 5m chart and the session expire at 2pm, write 13:55, if you are in 1H chart write 13:00...and so on), that's because after the end of the session, Tradingview will block any functions...since the market is closed, so we need to get the last bar of the session.

For the alerts, you just put your text and it's ready to go.

[image]

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a buch

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a checkmark beside the answer