# How to close the trade at the end of the day if I took a position in the same day according to the code?

Tags: pine-script

Code is working fine but at the end of the day, the position has to exit even though check1 = diplus >= 13. Means the position has to exit even though +DMI is not less than 13

```
//@version=4

 strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

 ema20 = ema(close, 20) 

 ema200 = ema(close, 200)

 len = input(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")

 lensig = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)

 [diplus, diminus, adx] = dmi(len, lensig)

 plot(diplus, color=color.blue, title="+DI")

 check = diplus > 13

 check1 = diplus < 13

 ema200_long = ema200 < close

 ema200_short = ema200 > close

 startTime = timestamp(2021, 03, 11, 09, 15)

 endTime = timestamp(2021, 05, 25, 12, 30)


//long
 if time >= startTime and time <=endTime and ema200_long

     strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100.0, when = check)



 strategy.close("long", qty_percent = 100, when = check1)    




 plot(ema200)

 plot(ema20)
```

Thank you and waiting for the reply.

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715920/how-to-send-alert-at-a-certain-time/67717214#67717214 here you will see how to create a session with start and end of the day and how to get them and use for signals, basically it's what you want

Comment: Edward, I have tried it but the exit is happening in the different date. PLease Check the image : https://ibb.co/NC6pnCF  and also check the code : https://justpaste.it/3qo66  Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code from that link is working well, you have only to change the hours and read the the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine but i suggest to add timezone to timestamp like this

```
timestamp("GMT+1", 2021, 05, 25, 12, 30)
```

Comment: Sorry but my question was something else and your answer was something else. I need to close the position at the end of the day.

Comment: I suggest the timezone because i think when variable is not completed correctly because tradingview server are on different timezone.

Comment: It's not about timezone, it's about close the position at the end of the day.

Comment: I am finding a hard time creating that closing the position at the end of the day. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
    strategy.close("short" )
    strategy.close("long" )
```